# Rails relationship and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, erb

I'm facing some confusing points with this question. Here is my user story:

"John need to create a (issue) task for the maintenance team with the train name and number, the parts that have problems, the priority and who is responsible for that task."

Each problem could have one or more solutions, and each part could have one problem.
A train could have a lot of issue (tasks), but not with the same problem.

So, based on that I created those

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :train_issues, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :train_issues, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }
end

class TrainIssue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
  has_many :train_displays
  has_many :train_display_problems
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :train_display_problems, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }
end

class TrainDisplay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :train_car
  belongs_to :train_issue
end

class TrainProblemAndSolution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :TrainDisplayProblem
  belongs_to :TrainDisplaySolution
end
```

I also have Train.rb and TrainCar.rb, they all related and this is working fine. I'm able to find the train_id by display and vice-versa.

My question is, how can I create a form for this user to create a issue with all those informations?
I read and did some examples with nestedForms but didn't work well, the form create a Issue, but not create the TrainIssue with the params.

Thank a lot!

Comment: You'll have to use nested forms, using `fields_for :association`. One of the easiest way to do that is using the `cocoon gem`! https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) for nested attributes. It allows to simply add a sub-form for them:

```
 <%= semantic_form_for @issue do |f| %>
   <%= f.inputs :title, :description %>
   <%= f.inputs :for => :trains_issues do |train_issue, index| %>
     <%= train_issue.input :name %>
     ...
   <%= end %>
   <%= f.actions %>
 <% end %>
```